Implementing Georeferencer transforms using QGIS Python API
I can see in QGIS Georeferencer plugin(under Layer menu) various transform algorithms in Transformation settings (under transformation type) such as 'Linear','Polynomial 1','Polynomial 2','Helmert','Projective' etc. How can we directly use these transformations using Qgis Python API ? Please guide.

The plugin itself does not have Python API access.
There is a Python Plugins extension for Georefrencer available for download, but is listed as experimental.
https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/GeorefExtension/version/3.0.5/
QGIS Python Plugins Repository
Version: [3383] Georeferencer Extension 3.0.5 Experimental
